# how to generate 3digit cyclic sequence number in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Pleas suggest how can I do this in Sql server 2005. It looks v2005 doesn't support?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DecSeq
AS decimal(3,0) 
START WITH 125
INCREMENT BY 25
MINVALUE 100
MAXVALUE 200
CYCLE
CACHE 3
```

Comment: You'd have to create your own table with an IDENTITY column, with a trigger I suppose to handle the cycle component (and you'd have no way to control caching).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, created Identity table and writing trigger to handle logic.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 does not support sequences. Implement them by yourself, possibly using a `Sequences` table.